# Is there anyway to "kill" system process by Visual Basic .NET 2008?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, process, kill

I tried a lot of ways to stop a system controlled process, tried google and even tried admin rights, or using `C:\Windows\System32\taskkill.exe`.

It's very easily done in Task Manager, but didn't find a way to do this by programming if there's a way in VS.NET not in Basic or 2008 say it.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class to find the process (using one of the `GetProcesses*` methods) and call the [`Kill`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx) method on it.

Of course, the account your application runs under needs to have enough permissions to do so.

Comment: exactly ,Is there a way to make it have the permission? it's always tells "access denied". even with admin rights

Comment: @ahmadmanga - Use `ProcessStartInfo` and provide the `UserName` and `Password` for an account that has such permissions.

Comment: But isn't it the same if you opened the program with the 'admin' of the pc ?

Comment: @ahmadmanga - Well, essentially, yes. There is no way for an account to simply gain privileges out of the air.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
Dim process As System.Diagnostics.Process = Nothing
Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo

psi.UseShellExecute = True
psi.FileName = “taskkill.exe”
psi.Arguments = “/F /IM notepad.exe”
process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi)
```

Comment: that's what I tried, it kills the ordinary processes but don't to System ones...(notpad isn't a system process)